# Notification Sticks (cannot be dismissed) after stopping a foreground service

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications, foreground-service

The notification sticks on the notification bar, not being able to be dismissed by horizontal swiping, when the following conditions are met:

- Android Pie (9.0)
- Calling `service.stopForeground(Service.STOP_FOREGROUND_DETACH)` right after calling `service.startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);`

Code Example:

```
service.startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
service.stopForeground(Service.STOP_FOREGROUND_DETACH);
```

Is there anything that I can do to force the foreground service to be stopped, even when it is called right after the `startForeground`, so the user can manually dismiss the notification?

Comment: add an action button in notification and on click on this stop service

Comment: Check in `Service.onCreate()` if you want it to be foreground or not (set a flag somewhere), and call `stopForeground()` at that time.